# Superclass mismatch for class ArtistsController and uninitialised constant Artist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an API in Rails and whenever I try to make a get request it gives me a "TypeError: superclass mismatch for class ArtistsController" error. Also it seems like there is a problem with the model too since whenever I try to create a new Artist object with Artist.create it gives me uninitialised constant Artist

My artists_controller.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    class ArtistsController < ::ApplicationController
      def index
        @artists = Artist.all
        render json: { status: 'Success', data: @artists }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end
```

My artist.rb

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
end
```

My schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20190217083634) do

  create_table "artists", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "bio",            limit: 65535
    t.string   "genre"
    t.integer  "price_per_hour"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the log entry for a specific request and the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: The request is made to http://localhost:3001/api/v1/artists, it's supposed to print all the items, the application trace is the following                         {
                "id": 0,
                "trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/artists_controller.rb:3:in `<module:V1>'"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/artists_controller.rb:2:in `<module:API>'"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/artists_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'"
            }

Comment: Error trace from logs? post the entire content. Code looks fine to me, atleast the Artist.create(name: "Some text") should work. Have you tried this operation from rails console.

Comment: I'm not getting any error in the logs, these are the errors I'm getting when I make the request in Postman. Yes, I have tried it in the console, that is when I get the uninitialised constant Artist.

Comment: I have realized that the reason I couldn't create an object was because I am using docker and to enter the development environment you have to use a different command. So I managed to create an object; however I still cannot make the request to the api. Docker might be the reason I cannot make the request too, but I can't see what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a module, Ruby is looking for the class `API::V1::Artist`.

You have to use the namespace resolution operator (`::`) to indicate to Ruby that you want to use the class `Artist`: `::Artist.all`